# TikZ: Extra space added to node text with pdfrender

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, rendering

In the following picture, a lot of extra space (relative to the true size of it, which is around 4cm by 3cm) is added when I use the `\prints` macro I defined in the preamble (line 14 according to TeXstudio), as seen in the first image; this macro uses the `pdfrender` package's macro `\textpdfrender`; also, for some reason, the `atril` document viewer shows part of the Q's tail in white, whereas TeXstudio's internal viewer renders it correctly in blue. Compare to the second image, in which `\prints[<colour>]{<letter>}` is replaced by `\textcolor{<colour>}{<letter>}` in the line after the `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%TEXT CODE!!!` comment (line 40 according to TeXstudio). The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\usetikzlibrary{
    positioning, 
    backgrounds,
%   calc
}

%%%%%%%%%DEF \prints MACRO
\newcommand{\prints}[2][black]{
    \textpdfrender{%
        TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,%
        FillColor=#1,%
        LineWidth=0.1pt,%
    }{#2}%
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    %%%FONT SIZE DETS. PICTURE SIZE
    \newdimen\ttext
    \ttext = 80pt
    \fontsize{\ttext}{22}\fontfamily{trjn}\selectfont\par
    %%%%%/FONTSIZE.

    %%%%QED NODE
    \node[
        inner ysep = 1.5pt, 
        inner xsep = -1.7pt,
        outer sep = 0pt, 
%       draw, 
%       ultra thin
        ] (q) at (0,0) 
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%TEXT CODE!!!
    {
        \raisebox{-0.22em}{\prints[cyan!80!black]{Q}} 
        \kern -1.05ex \raisebox{0.22em}{\prints[red!80!black]{E}} 
        \kern -1.1ex\hbox{\prints[green!80!black]{D}} 
    };
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%/QED

    %%%EXTRA NODE FOR MORE SPACE
    \node [below = 0.18\ttext of current bounding box.south, inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt, anchor = south] (a) {};

    %%%BG RECTANGLE
    \begin{scope}[
        on background layer, 
        every path/.style = {
        line width = 0.25pt, 
        opacity = 0.5
    }
    ]
    \fill[
    opacity = 1,
    top color = gray, 
    bottom color = gray!5,
    ] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would really like to have the second picture but with the outlined letters as in the first; I realise I can get the second image by kerning enough negative space on each letter, but I rather know why `pdfrender` adds this space and how to remove it, if possible. I also tried using the `contour` package, but I get the third image (after modifying the number of copies the `\contour` command prints; the image is done with 7, but I wasn't satisfied with the results, specially on the arm of the E). Thanks!!

[image: With <code>\textpdfrender</code>]
[image: Without <code>\textpdfrender</code>]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically all of this comes from spurious spaces (and has nothing to do with Ti*k*Z per se). Ironically this construction requires precisely one space between Q and E and one between E and D. I added `%` at various places to remove these spaces, such as at the beginning of the node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\usetikzlibrary{
    positioning, 
    backgrounds,
%   calc
}

%%%%%%%%%DEF \prints MACRO
\newcommand{\prints}[2][black]{%
    \textpdfrender{%
        TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,%
        FillColor=#1,%
        LineWidth=0.1pt,%
    }{#2}%
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newdimen\ttext
\ttext=80pt%
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    %%%FONT SIZE DETS. PICTURE SIZE
%     \fontsize{\ttext}{22}\fontfamily{trjn}\selectfont%\par
    %%%%%/FONTSIZE.

    %%%%QED NODE
    \node[
        inner ysep = 1.5pt, 
        inner xsep = -1.7pt,
        outer sep = 0pt, 
%       draw, 
       font=\fontsize{\ttext}{22}\fontfamily{trjn}\selectfont,
%       ultra thin
        ] (q) at (0,0) 
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%TEXT CODE!!!
    {%
        \raisebox{-0.22em}{\prints[cyan!80!black]{Q}} %<- need one space 
        \kern -1.05ex \raisebox{0.22em}{\prints[red!80!black]{E}} % 
        \kern -1.1ex\hbox{\prints[green!80!black]{D}}%
    };
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%/QED

    %%%EXTRA NODE FOR MORE SPACE
    \node [below = 0.18\ttext of current bounding box.south, inner sep = 0pt, outer sep = 0pt, anchor = south] (a) {};

    %%%BG RECTANGLE
    \begin{scope}[
        on background layer, 
        every path/.style = {
        line width = 0.25pt, 
        opacity = 0.5
    }
    ]
    \fill[
    opacity = 1,
    top color = gray, 
    bottom color = gray!5,
    ] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!!! Could you tell me why those spaces are relevant (or point me towards an appropriate source)? I specially want to know the reason behind the "ironic" spaces (ironic, indeed)! Many thanks and kudos!

Comment: @ÓscarGuajardo Basically every `%` I added was to kill a space. A very important one was at the beginning of the node `{%`. Then I added another `%` after `\kern -1.1ex\hbox{\prints[green!80!black]{D}}`. I also made `\fontsize{\ttext}{22}\fontfamily{trjn}\selectfont` part of the `font` information of the node. You could get rid of the spaces after `\raisebox{-0.22em}{\prints[cyan!80!black]{Q}}` and `\raisebox{0.22em}{\prints[red!80!black]{E}}` by changing the kerning, but I think there is no real need for that since the result looks good.

Comment: The result looks quite nice; but my question was as for the reason why the spaces between letters are needed. I understand the need for commenting out blank spaces I hadn't noticed, but why add the others?

Comment: @ÓscarGuajardo I obviously did not invent the nice series of letters. However, it seems to me that whoever did that added the kerning under the assumption that there will be spaces.